# Difference between E-Trip circuit breaker and Mechanical Trip breaker

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

Trying to order a 19" distribution breaker panel.

All small loads, (3A..7A) but I am being asked do I want Mechanical trip or E-Trip bullet breakers. The description on their quotes say Electro-Mechanical or Mid-Trip.

On a high level, what's the difference between the two?

Comment: Provide links to the parts.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?